# Ubuntu is not finding swap partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, swap

I booted Ubuntu on to a new computer today. I created 3 partitions 20g for operating system 200g encrypted /home and 12g swap. But `sudo swapon -s` brings up nothing and when I boot it also say swap not set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use `parted -l` to check it is indeed a swap partition.

Second, run `sudo mkswap /dev/sda3` (or whatever your swap partition is..) to create a swap partition. Do make sure it's the right one!

Third, use `blkid` to get a UUID for it.

Fourth, `sudo vi /etc/fstab` (or whatever editor you prefer to `vi`!) & enter the UUID - there should be a line similar to `UUID=7qluevy34fhi77u none swap sw 0 0` in there, if not then write one, ensure the UUID matches step 3. I *always* cut/paste these.

Finally, try the `sudo swapon` & check again.

Comment: Excellent answer! (and an upvote!)

Answer (score 0):

SWAP partition mount automatic after install OS.

You can see your SWAP using command: free (there you can see real RAM and SWAP)
Also you can see SWAP partition on FSTAB in file /etc/fstab

Answer (score 0):

I had repartitioned my drives and wound up moving my swap to a new partition.  You need to edit fstab-> sudo gedit /etc/fstab (or whatever editor) and change the UUID= to the new UUID number.  The line in fstab will look something like this

UUID=7f5eb2b4-ff71-4cf8-82cc-90dc6b8d4b16 none            swap    sw              0       0

to find ID open terminal and sudo blkid.  Copy and paste it into fstab.  Reboot.  Open up disks, and you should see if the swap got mounted correctly.